# Find the acceleration and velocity functions of the vector with initial conditions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

The given is
$$a(t)=t\pmb j+t \pmb k $$
$$t=3 \space,\pmb v(1)=2 \pmb j \space ,\pmb r(1)=0$$
First differentiating the acceleration function:
$$\pmb v(t)=(\frac{1}{2}t^2+C)\pmb j +(\frac{t^2}{2}+C_1)\pmb k$$
Solving for C with the given $\pmb v(t)$ function:
$$C=2-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$C=\frac{3}{2}$$
Thus the velocity function becomes:
$$\pmb v(t)=\frac{3t^2}{2}\pmb j+(\frac{t^2}{2}+C_1)$$
Am I correct in my calculations?

Comment: You are correct, but you can do more. Because $v(1) = 2\hat{j}$ it means the $\hat{k}$ component is zero, so $\frac{1}{2} + C_{1} = 0$ and you find $C_{1}$.

Comment: So the vector function should be$\frac{3t^2}{2} \pmb j + (\frac{t^2-1}{2}) \pmb k$?

Comment: It says it is wrong, could I be that I need to put it in component quotation?

Comment: Wait, there is something wrong with your $\hat{j}$ entry because its derivative should be $t$ (since you have to recover the acceleration). It is actually $v(t) = (\frac{t^{2}}{2}+\frac{3}{2})\hat{j}+(\frac{t^{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{2})\hat{k}$.

Comment: Sorry, what is 'it'? I don't get it. Is it your pc or something?

Comment: That was it, thanks man

Comment: Oh, ok! No problem!